# for loop does not work in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am trying to plot two datasets on the same graph. Both data are for the same day and the x-axis in both cases is a time feed complete with date and time (in the format dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss). However the number of observations can be different in both cases and times at which values are observed can also be different. When i do the plotting for each excel file in the folder separately, the code works fine. However I have to draw the same kinds of plot for each day of the whole month (each plot will be based on data from one file). So, I put the code in a for loop. But to my utter surprise, addaxis will no longer work. The error that I have been getting is :

```
Error in ==> addaxis at 108
hplt = plot(varargin{:});

Error in ==> crossplot at 17
addaxis(putdata.datenos,calldata.ltp,'r-');
```

where crossplot is the name of my script file. and addaxis is a function I downloaded and installed from file exchange. It basically provides a convenient way of plot two or more different axes in the same graph.

Now I know that the number of data points are different in each case. But still the code works fine when I run it individually for each file in workspace. It only gives the error when I put it into a for loop. Can you please help me sort this out? I am completely flummoxed by what is going on? The code I am using is as follows:

```
cd('H:/heckyl intern/no analysis/pivots/ce 5200 28 jun');

callnames=dir('*.xlsx');

cd('H:/heckyl intern/no analysis/pivots/pe 5200 28 jun');

putnames=dir('*.xlsx');

for i=1:length(callnames)
    calldata=csv2struct(['H:/heckyl intern/no analysis/pivots/ce 5200 28 jun/' 
                        callnames(i).name]);
    putdata=csv2struct(['H:/heckyl intern/no analysis/pivots/pe 5200 28 jun/' 
                        putnames(i).name]);
    [tempname remain]=strtok(callnames(i).name,'.');
    figname=[tempname '.fig'];
    calldata.datenos=datenum(calldata.xchangefeedtime);
    putdata.datenos=datenum(putdata.xchangefeedtime);
    plot(calldata.datenos,calldata.ltp);
    addaxis(putdata.datenos,calldata.ltp,'r-');
    saveas(gcf,figname);
    close(gcf);
end
```

PS: I am very sorry for long query. But I am new user to matlab and don't know the whole Matlab jargon. And this is my first question on this board. Anyways, thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Since you're new, you can try using the help files found in matlab by typing: doc for help for Also, try indenting your code for better readability.

Comment: You can try running your code in debugging mode step by step to watch your variables. Alternatively, you can add some `disp` statements to figure out what is going on.

Comment: You should check whether the number of filenames and their order is the same in your variables `callnames`and `putnames`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about addaxis, my Matlab doesn't have it. Is it the one off the file exchange? You could just use plot and hold, you don't need addaxis by the sound of it. Try this:

```
    for i=1:length(callnames)
        calldata=csv2struct(['H:/heckyl intern/no analysis/pivots/ce 5200 28 jun/' 
                            callnames(i).name]);
        putdata=csv2struct(['H:/heckyl intern/no analysis/pivots/pe 5200 28 jun/' 
                            putnames(i).name]);
        [tempname remain]=strtok(callnames(i).name,'.');
        calldata.datenos=datenum(calldata.xchangefeedtime);
        putdata.datenos=datenum(putdata.xchangefeedtime);
        plot(calldata.datenos,calldata.ltp);
        hold on;
        plot(putdata.datenos,calldata.ltp,'r-')
        figname=[tempname '.fig'];
        saveas(gcf,figname);
        close(gcf);

    end
```